# FOSMessageBundle - How to send a message without the field form recipient

Tags: php, symfony

I've hide my recipient field form and now I would like to understand where in the controller I can tell the value of the recipient

MessageController :

```
/**
 * Create a new message thread
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function newThreadAction()
{
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_message.new_thread_form.factory')->create();
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_message.new_thread_form.handler');

    if ($message = $formHandler->process($form)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_message_thread_view', array(
            'threadId' => $message->getThread()->getId()
        )));
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSMessageBundle:Message:newThread.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'data' => $form->getData()
    ));
}
```

$form math to :

```
class NewThreadMessageFormFactory extends AbstractMessageFormFactory
{
    /**
     * Creates a new thread message
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $message = $this->createModelInstance();

        return $this->formFactory->createNamed($this->formName, $this->formType, $message);
    }
}
```

$formHandler match to :

```
class NewThreadMessageFormHandler extends AbstractMessageFormHandler
{
    /**
     * Composes a message from the form data
     *
     * @param AbstractMessage $message
     * @return MessageInterface the composed message ready to be sent
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException if the message is not a NewThreadMessage
     */
    public function composeMessage(AbstractMessage $message)
    {
        if (!$message instanceof NewThreadMessage) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Message must be a NewThreadMessage instance, "%s" given', get_class($message)));
        }

        return $this->composer->newThread()
                    ->setSubject($message->getSubject())
                    ->addRecipient($message->getRecipient())
                    ->setSender($this->getAuthenticatedParticipant())
                    ->setBody($message->getBody())
                    ->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I hope have some solutions !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to set up the recipient t in the controller?

Comment: because I don't want the field recipient in the view

Answer (score 1):

You could set the form data of the form, after you created the form.
My form is resolved in the following way:

In your newThreadAction:

```
$form = $this->getFormForNewThreadAction($account);
```

Keep in mind that $account has the ParticipantInterface in my example.

In your MessageController:

```
/**
 * @param ParticipantInterface $account
 * @return \FOS\MessageBundle\FormFactory\Form|FormInterface
 */
private function getFormForNewThreadAction(ParticipantInterface $account)
{
    $form = $this->getNewThreadFormFactory()->create();
    $preSetFormData = $this->getPreSetFormData($account, $form);
    $form->setData($preSetFormData);

    return $form;
}

/**
 * @param ParticipantInterface $account
 * @param Form $form
 * @return NewThreadMessage
 */
private function getPreSetFormData(ParticipantInterface $account, Form $form)
{
    $recipients = new ArrayCollection();
    $recipients->add($account);

    /** @var NewThreadMessage $newThreadMessage */
    $newThreadMessage = $form->getData();
    $newThreadMessage->setRecipients($recipients);

    return $newThreadMessage;
}
```

The form needs his NewThreadMessage as data and you can set your recipients there. That is all folks.